# Shift non-periodic values in data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `data` dictionary like this:

```py
data = {
    'new_value': [
        '100', '100',
        '250', '250',
        '250', '50',
        '90', '90',
        '90', '90'
    ],
    'prev_value': [
        'None', 'None',
        'None', 'None',
        'None', 'None',
        'None', 'None',
        'None', 'None'
    ]
}

    new_value   prev_value
0        100    None
1        100    None
2        250    None
3        250    None
4        250    None
5         50    None
6         90    None
7         90    None
8         90    None
9         90    None
```

And I would expect to get another dictionary `exp_result` like this:

```py
exp_result = {
    'new_value': [
        '100', '100',
        '250', '250',
        '250', '50',
        '90', '90',
        '90', '90'
    ],
    'prev_value': [
        '100', '100',
        '100', '100',
        '100', '250',
        '50', '50',
        '50', '50'
    ]
}

   new_value    prev_value
0        100    100
1        100    100
2        250    100
3        250    100
4        250    100
5         50    250
6         90    50
7         90    50
8         90    50
9         90    50
```

I tried [`pandas.Series.shift()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) function, but my data isn't periodic and I have no idea now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is convert all values without last consecutives to missing values by [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html), then [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) for values to next groups, forward filling missing values by previous values by `ffill` and last replace first missing values by originals by `fillna`:

```
m = df['new_value'].shift(-1).eq(df['new_value'])
df['prev_value'] = df['new_value'].mask(m).shift().ffill().fillna(df['new_value'])
print (df)

  new_value prev_value
0       100        100
1       100        100
2       250        100
3       250        100
4       250        100
5        50        250
6        90         50
7        90         50
8        90         50
9        90         50
```